# External stylesheets for shadow dom in web components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm learning web components with a shadow root and can't seem to find on google if loading external stylesheets is possible with out-of-the-box code?  I am NOT using polymer or any other web component library (yet).  Code below:

```
<script src="../../libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var hollaProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
    hollaProto.createdCallback = function () {
        var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
        var content = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]').import.querySelector("div");

        $("button[data-command=holla]", content).on("click", function () { alert("Holla!"); });

        shadow.appendChild(content);
    };
    var hollaWidget = document.registerElement("holla-back", {
        prototype: hollaProto
    });
</script>
<div class="holla-back">
    <button data-command="holla">Holla!</button>
</div>
```

If I put my link tag up top, above the first script tag, I style the whole web age, but not the web component.

If I put it under `div.holla-back` it doesn't style anything.

How do you use external stylesheets with web components?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Link tags are inert in Shadow DOM [according to the spec](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#inertness-of-html-elements-in-a-shadow-tree). However, you can use `@import`, though that has its own performance issues.

The way Polymer works around this is it looks at the `link` tags and uses `xhr` to load those styles and apply them.

**edit:**

The folks working on Shadow DOM are aware of this shortcoming and that it needs to be fixed. Hopefully in the future we can come up with a system that supports external stylesheets.

Comment: Can you clarify using @import?

Comment: You can do something like this: http://jsbin.com/qefoyi/1/edit but heavy use of @import is going to cause a lot of http requests and really slow down your page. The recommended approach is to use style elements with all your markup inside them already.

Comment: I see what you mean.  It's ugly but achieves what I wanted, though you're right in that it adds a lot of requests.

Comment: @robdodson Couldn't the same argument be used though to say you shouldn't use `link` in your document headers either? Yet `link` in that context is usually considered best practice.

Comment: This answer could really benefit from some references or links to more information. For example, an explanation of what performance issues there are with `@import`, and a link to a place where the "folks working on Shadow DOM" are working to address this shortcoming would be great. I haven't been able to find any discussion threads mentioning this on the W3C mailing list archives...

Comment: I can't seem to get @import working inside an angular2 compenent with ViewEncapsulation shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Shadow DOM doesn't react to link tags. Infact, Chrome 41 throws an error when you use link tags. We have worked around that limitation by inlining CSS classes at the build time using vulcanize. This turned out to be quite handy in separating your CSS and the component definition.